# Can't see Launch Synapse Studio or Create Workspace options in Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azure-stream-analytics, azure-synapse

I got a requirement from one of our client to build a poc on Azure Synapse Analytics. I have Azure subscriptions and subscribed for Azure Synapse. When i login into Azure Synapse, i can't see "Launch Synapse Studio" or "Create Workspace" option.
Can somebody help me who to get started with Synapse.

Your help is much appreciated !

Regards,

Aditya

Comment: Please add some snapshots or more information on what you is your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Synapse Analytics is currently in private preview. That is the reason you cannot create a workspace. To be able to create a workspace you will have to join the private preview [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/synapse-analytics/request-for-preview/).

For more information, please visit [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/44612) Web resource.

Azure users that have been accepted on the private preview can access their Synapse Workspace on [this](http://web.azuresynapse.net/) URL.

Comment: Hi Alberto, Thanks for the reply. I have registered for private preview last week till now i haven't received any mail from Microsoft Azure. Do you know how much time they will take to respond or any criteria for accepting the private preview? Please reply

Comment: I still don't know how much time they take to register a customer for the preview, but maybe you will like to see this documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/overview-what-is / https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/tree/master/articles/synapse-analytics

Answer (score 0):

With the Recent Microsoft Build 2020, Azure Synapses workspace is moved into Public Preview

[Link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/44612#issuecomment-633627381)

You can now start using this